# unable to implement method correctly

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote this program to arrange the numbers in ascending order . But it is not giving the desired output.I have analysed the program properly and am aware that i am unable to implement `sort` function *(below)* properly .  Please suggest what should be done in order that this program outputs correctly:

I have given sample outputs below the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class sorter
{

  static int biggest;
  static int arr[];
  static int sortedArray[];
  static int count;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.print("How many numbers you want to enter : ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String x = br.readLine();
    try
    {
      count = Integer.parseInt(x);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      System.out.println(exc);
    }
    arr = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " number : ");
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      try
      {
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(br2.readLine());
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("We'll sort the numbers now !");

    sortedArray = new int[count];


    biggest = getBiggest(arr[0]);  // get The biggest number

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      sortedArray[i] = sort(arr[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("SortedArray is : " + sortedArray[i]);
    }
  }

  public static int getBiggest(int big)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if (big < arr[i])
      {
        big = arr[i];
      }
    }
    return big;
  }

  public static int sort(int small)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if (small > arr[i])
      {
        small = arr[i];
        System.out.println("BIGGEST-->" + biggest);
        arr[i] =
            ++biggest;   // i replace the smallest number with the biggest number after storing the smallest number in small
        biggest++;
      }
    }
    return small;
  }
}
```

**In this i don't get the desired output . I am unable to perform this task . The biggest problem in this program is the working of function sort . How can i improve it's working ? so that it outputs me the desired result**

### Here are some sample outputs from the program :

```
How many numbers you want to enter : 4
Enter the 1 number : 6
Enter the 2 number : 7
Enter the 3 number : 8
Enter the 4 number : 1
We'll sort the numbers now !
BIGGEST-->8
SortedArray is : 1
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6




How many numbers you want to enter : 6
Enter the 1 number : 6
Enter the 2 number : 8
Enter the 3 number : 55
Enter the 4 number : 99
Enter the 5 number : 44
Enter the 6 number : 557
We'll sort the numbers now !
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
SortedArray is : 6
```

Comment: How about some formatting in that code?

Comment: We'd all appreciate it if you could reduce your code to a much smaller example instead of just posting ALL your code and saying "there's a problem in it".  First of all, figure out what section of code is giving you a problem, share what you think might be wrong with it and perhaps include some sample code to illustrate the error.  Make it easier on us _please_.

Comment: You have made no effort at all to reduce your code to the smallest example that displays the problem - please do so.

Comment: @ Bohemian To tell what the problem is almost the whole code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Arrays.sort()`?  It would make your code a lot shorter:

```
//[...]

System.out.println("We'll sort the numbers now !");
Arrays.sort(arr);
for(int i : arr) {
    System.out.println("SortedArray is : " + i);
}
```

Comment: How can i sort 2d array using this ?

Comment: @grassPro - What are the semantics for performing your 2d sort?  Do you just need to sort the contents of each logical row, or do you need to sort the row contents and then apply some ordering operation to the rows themselves?  Or do you want to sort everything as if the 2d array is one big array?

Comment: I just want to sort the contents of the first column and then put back the contents of second column to which they belonged _(i.e infront of each belonging row)_. **example** `[5][6] , [1][8] , [9][0]` after sorting 2d array becomes `[1][8] , [5][6] , [9] [0]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the line

```
sortedArray[i] = sort(arr[0]);
```

You are sending always the same element and since the sort returns that one or a bigger element of the array.

Maybe you should get some ideas first. [Quicksort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) is one of the most popular sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using arrays? Just use a Collection, like List:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
... for all lines:
list.add(Integer.parseInt(br2.readLine()));
...
Collections.sort(list);
```

And you're done. That's all there is to it.